# How do I create unique constraint for multiple columns?

Tags: sql, go, go-gorm

I have following structure and would like to create unique index on (UserId and Contact). Is this possible in gorm?

```
type Contact struct {
    gorm.Model
    UserId    uint   `gorm:"index;not null"`
    Contact string `gorm:"type:text;not null"`
}
```

I would like to create table something like

```
CREATE TABLE contact (...column definitions ...) 
    CONSTRAINT constraint1
    UNIQUE (user_id, contact)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The doc on [models](http://gorm.io/docs/models.html) specifies the following for `INDEX` and `UNIQUE_INDEX`:

> INDEX Create index with or without name, same name creates composite
> indexes
>
> UNIQUE_INDEX  Like INDEX, create unique index

This means that two fields with the same `UNIQUE_INDEX` name will create a composite unique index.

The full struct definition to use a composite index named `compositeindex` using your example becomes:

```golang
type Contact struct {
    gorm.Model
    UserId    uint   `gorm:"UNIQUE_INDEX:compositeindex;index;not null"`
    Contact   string `gorm:"UNIQUE_INDEX:compositeindex;type:text;not null"`
}
```

Comment: `UNIQUE_INDEX` did not work for me (without showing any error); I had to use `uniqueIndex` instead

Comment: Same, uniqueIndex worked for me.